# LambdaFunction - Value of property Variables must be an object with String (or simple type) properties

Tags: node.js, deployment, serverless

I am using serverless to deploy my Lambda based application. It was deploying just fine, and then it stopped for some reason. I paired down the entire package to the serverless.yml below and one function in the handler - but I keep getting this error:

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

An error occurred: TestLambdaFunction - Value of property Variables must be an object with String (or simple type) properties.

Stack Trace --------------------------------------------
```

Here is the serverless.yml

```
# serverless.yml
service: some-api
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: prod
  region: us-east-1
  iamRoleStatements:
    $ref: ./user-policy.json
  environment:
    config:
      region: us-east-1
plugins:
  - serverless-local-dev-server
  - serverless-dynamodb-local
  - serverless-step-functions
package:
  exclude:
    - .gitignore
    - package.json
    - README.md
    - .git
    - ./**.test.js
functions:
  test:
    handler: handler.test
    events:
      - http: GET test
resources:
  Outputs:
    NewOutput:
      Description: Description for the output
      Value: Some output value
```

Test Lambda Function in Package

```
#handler.test
module.exports.test = (event, context, callback) => {
  callback(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'sadfasd',
      input: event
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out, this issue does not have any relationship to the Lambda function. Here is the issue that caused the error.

This does ***NOT*** work:

```
  environment:
    config:
      region: us-east-1
```

This **DOES** work:

```
  environment:
    region: us-east-1
```

Simply put, I don't think you can have more than one level in your yaml environment variables.

Even if you try `sls print` as a sanity check, this issue will not pop up. Only in `sls deploy`.

You have been warned, and hopefully saved!

Comment: Same problem. Thank you.

Comment: Somebody put Refs in my project's environment variables. The strange thing is that the failures are intermittent!

Answer (score 0):

Other thing that might cause this kind of error is using invalid yaml syntax.

It's easy to get confused about this.

Valid syntax for environment variables

```
environment:
  key: value
```

Invalid syntax for environment variables

```
environment:
  - key: value
```

Notice little dash in the code below?

In yaml syntax `-` means array and therefore, code below is interpreted as array, not object.

So that's why error tells "Value of property Variables must be an object with String (or simple type) properties."

This can be easily fixed by removing `-` in front of all keys.